# Grunt task not calling external javascript task

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, gruntjs

I am trying to insert data to mongodb using a grunt task. Init.js is the file which is located in "tasks" directory. So, i registered the task as:

```
grunt.registerTask('dbinit', function () {
grunt.task.loadTasks('tasks');
}
```

tasks directory has Init.js:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 config = require('/lib/config/config.js'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 dbmodel = require('/lib/models/user.js'),
 db;

mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('open', function () { 
var user = new dbmodel.User({
 userId : 'bond007'
});
console.log('Adding seed user: '+user);

newUser.save(function (err, product, numberAffected) {
if (err) {
   console.log(err); 
} else {
  console.log("saved user: "+user.userId);
}  
db.close();

});
});
```

The problem is that Init.js is never called. I am not sure if it is an async issue or issue with calling Init.js but I see the "dbinit" task "Done without errors".

Answer (score 0):

Grunt tasks by default execute synchronously, the task will finish and not wait for the mongoose connection to open. Use `this.async()` within the task to have the task wait.

A better strategy might be to wrap parts within `tasks/Init.js` in a task like such:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
config = require('/lib/config/config.js'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
dbmodel = require('/lib/models/user.js'),
db;

grunt.registerTask('dbinit', function() {
  var done = this.async();
  mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
  db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('open', function () { 
    var user = new dbmodel.User({
      userId : 'bond007'
    });
    console.log('Adding seed user: '+user);

    newUser.save(function (err, product, numberAffected) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); 
      } else {
        console.log("saved user: "+user.userId);
      }  
      db.close();
      done(); // Call done to close the task
    });
  });
});
```

Then just use `grunt.loadTasks('tasks');` in your gruntfile.